# Installing Hadoop in full distributed mode using VM VirtualBox on Windows Machines

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop in Pseudo-Distribution Mode using Oracle VM VirtualBox (https://github.com/AmanpreetSingh-GitHub/Hadoop) on Windows 10 machine and it is working perfectly fine and running my MapReduce, Pig, Hive, Sqoop programs.

Now I want to install Hadoop in full distributed mode using Oracle VM VirtualBox on four Windows 10 machines. Could you please let me know how to proceed for this? Any links to resources that briefly tells that will be really helpful.

Comment: any reason those machines can't just run some sort of linux directly?

Comment: I am doing a POC on my company machines that have pre-installed Windows 10 image (this is to showcase to the clients). Only once this gets approved, we will go forward and install linux directly on these machines.